# MySQL - Query Multiple values in a single column

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am currently working on a site utilizing the WP-Property plugin for Wordpress.

Basically I am attempting to display a counter next to a text search link for a particular price range.

Below is the query I am running which does the price range count perfectly fine.

```
  $apartprice1 = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_value BETWEEN 50000 AND 74999");
if (0 < $apartprice1) $apartprice1 = number_format($apartprice1);
```

I would however like to extend on  this to display only "Apartments" which are within this particular price range.
Now bear in mind that within the `meta_value` column the property type values (apartments, houses, freeholds) are also stored.

Any boffins about whom can demystify this for me please?

edit:  Some further elaboration below:

```
Table name is postmeta

meta_id     post_id     meta_key        meta_value

348         41          property_type   apartment
358         41          price           698000
```

So I would like to be able to do a count of a particular price range which is also based on a specific property type

Comment: "within the `meta_value` column the property type values (apartments, houses, freeholds) are also stored." - Well, you could, at least, provide an example. I have no idea what to make of this.

Comment: Could you provide a table structure?

Comment: @ChrisHenry I was in the middle of an edit -is that sufficient?

Comment: @MihaiTodor updated the question with more detail

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for displaying the count for each of the property values the `partments`, `houses`, `freeholds`, you should add a `GROUP BY property_type`

```
SELECT  property_type, COUNT(*) 
FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
WHERE meta_value BETWEEN 50000 AND 74999
GROUP BY property_type
```

**Update:** You have to *pivot* your rows into columns in order to get the data the way you described like so:

```
SELECT t.property_type, COUNT(t.post_id) AS 'type count'
FROM
(
   SELECT t.post_id,
     MAX(CASE WHEN t.meta_key = 'property_type' THEN t.meta_value END) AS property_type,
     MAX(CASE WHEN t.meta_key = 'price' THEN CAST(t.meta_value AS DECIMAL) END) AS Price
   FROM postmeta t
   GROUP BY t.post_id
) t
WHERE t.property_type = 'apartment' 
  AND t.Price BETWEEN 600000 AND 700000
GROUP BY t.property_type
```

Note that the `meta_value` field is supposed to store both a string values for property types as well as numeric values for `price`s so I `CAST` it to `DECIMAL` in order to select it as numeric data type so that you can perform calculation on it later on. I also used `MAX` as an aggregate function as a work around to pivot the rows.

Here is a [**demo in SQL fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59a1d/5).

This what you usually encounter in such a design model which is what they called [**Entity–attribute–value model**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model). You can find a lot of useful thread about this data model under the tag [eav](/questions/tagged/eav). You can also find more useful pages about this design model in  [the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8609588/722783)

Comment: I have updated with the table structure.  Not quite what I was looking for, but thanks none the less!

Answer (score 0):

This table structure makes it somewhat difficult/inefficient to do the type of multifacet searching you're looking for. To ensure that all `WHERE` clauses are met, you'll need to `INNER JOIN` the `meta` table to itself. This gives you a temporary data format that's bit more suitable for your query.

```
SELECT m1.post_id
FROM meta m1
INNER JOIN meta m2 ON m1.post_id = m2.post_id
WHERE m1.meta_key = 'price'
AND m1.meta_value
BETWEEN 50000 AND 7000000 AND m2.meta_key = 'property_type'
AND m2.meta_value = 'apartment'
```

Keep in mind, for every additional facet you add, you'll need to do an additional `INNER JOIN`. Also, if you don't have one already, I'd recommend an index on the `post_id` column.

To get the count, just change what's in the `SELECT` clause.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM meta m1
INNER JOIN meta m2 ON m1.post_id = m2.post_id
WHERE m1.meta_key = 'price'
AND m1.meta_value
BETWEEN 50000 AND 7000000 AND m2.meta_key = 'property_type'
AND m2.meta_value = 'apartment'
```

Comment: Nice one - this is heading towards what I am after.  One thing though, this returns the post_id values, how would I go about getting a count of how many of the posts (apartments) are within the given price range? (apologies - not quite mastered sql queries yet)